# Textview hidden on overflow

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout for a listview:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblDate"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/list_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_site_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblDesc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/list_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_site_content" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/lblImp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/list_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_site_content"
            android:gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

How can i make the text inside the TextView @+id/lblDesc don't push the textview @+id/lblImp out of the screen?

This is an example of what happens:
[[image: 1]]

Also using the relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgTipoDebito"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_image_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_image_size"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/lblData"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/list_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_site_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgTipoDebito"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/lblDescrizione"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/list_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_site_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblData"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/lblImporto"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/list_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_site_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The results is this:
[[image: 2]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of suggestions.

**RelativeLayout**

Wrap the `TextView` within a relative layout and use the following properties:

`toLeftOf`
`toRightOf`

The above properties will force the `TextView` to not overflow on to the next `TextView`.

**Why use `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`?**

In this case, the purpose is to prevent OverFlow of the TextView's.

**LinearLayout with Weights**

You can use your existing implementation but introduce the `weight` property as part of the `TextView`'s. This will only work however if you make the `width` property of each `TextView` 0.

e.g.

`width="0dp"`
`weight="1"`

Again, this will force the TextView to remain it's size and to prevent Overflow.

**Update**

As mentioned, you need to use `toRightOf` and `toLeftOf`.

Therefore, if we concentrate on the middle `TextView`, you need to add:

```
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/lblImporto"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lblData"
```

This will make sure that the `TextView` is to the right of `lblData` and to the left of `lblImporto` - Making it not overflow.

Comment: I tried both solutions, but do not seem to work. You can see what happens with the RelativeLayout above.